# How to access contents of an array in Laravel blades

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I have a question on accessing data on blades in Laravel.

For exmaple, I have this:

```
{
   "is_pay":"1",
   "detail":[
      {"title":"product1","unit":"exist","count":"1","per_price":"300000","sum_price":"300000","off":"10000"},
      {"title":"product2","unit":"exist","count":"2","per_price":"200000","sum_price":"400000","off":"20000"}
   ]
}
```

I can properly access `is_pay` but I don't know how to get `title` data at `detail`...

So if you know, please let me know, I would really appreciate that...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `foreach` like:

```
@foreach ($variableOnBlade as $detail)
    {{ $detail->title }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of objects. To acces the first object try this:
detail[0].title and for the second object detail[1].title. Not tested but should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to take raw json and output it, you need to first decode it, then you can loop through it and echo it out via your view like so...

```
 @foreach(json_decode($rawJson, true)['detail'] as $detail) 
        {{ $detail['title'] }}
 @endforeach
```